# Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, admob

I have made a free android game and I wanted to add a banner to it. I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play-xml) and I don't know why it won't work.

When I run my game on the emulator in LogCat I see a message "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad." and when I install the game on my phone I also don't see any ads.

Here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="hidden"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = true;
        cfg.useCompass = true;

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        initialize (new RedSquare(), cfg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      adView.pause();
      super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      adView.destroy();
      super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show ads in libgdx you need to initialize your app **for view**. So, replace all this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

initialize (new RedSquare(), cfg);
```

With this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
View gameView = initializeForView(new RedSquare(), cfg);

AdView AdView = new AdView(this);
AdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
AdView.setAdUnitId("***"); //The AdUnitId
AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequest.addTestDevice("***"); //Your Test device if any
AdView.loadAd(adRequest.build());

layout.addView(gameView);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

layout.addView(AdView, adParams);

setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found out using `adMob` defining the layout explicitely in a file could be a huge headache generator, as sometimes it might turn impredictable with some parameter and layout combination. What always seems to work is adding the `AdView` dynamically to some `LinearLayout`.

This should work:

```
final LinearLayout fragLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
final AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
adView.setAdUnitId("your-admob-id");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

// Here you'll append the new AdView
final LinearLayout publiView = (LinearLayout) fragLayout.findViewById(R.id.publi);
publiView.addView(adView);

final AdRequest.Builder adReq = new AdRequest.Builder();
// You should include a line like this for testing purposes,
// but only after you've tested whether your AdView works!
// This will prevent your ad being loaded each time you test
// your ad, so it will prevent you being blocked from AdMob.
// You'll find your device_id in the LogCat.
adReq.addTestDevice("your_device_id");

final AdRequest adRequest = adReq.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**---- EDIT ----**

This implementation is for `Fragment`s, you probably are running an `Activity` and that's why you're getting those errors.

- Replace `getActivity()` with `this`
- The `inflater` simply (as it name says) inflates a new `LinearLayout` from a layout file. This means I have defined a layout which I've called `your_layout` and defined inside a `LinearLayout`. The inflater just creates an instance of that `LinearLayout. In your case probably it's not necessary.

I'm adding a code that probably will work for you:

```
final LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_linearlayout_id_where_you_want_to_put_your_adview);

final AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdUnitId("your-admob-id");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

yourLayout.addView(adView);

final AdRequest.Builder adReq = new AdRequest.Builder();
// You should include a line like this for testing purposes,
// but only after you've tested whether your AdView works!
// This will prevent your ad being loaded each time you test
// your ad, so it will prevent you being blocked from AdMob.
// You'll find your device_id in the LogCat.
adReq.addTestDevice("your_device_id");

final AdRequest adRequest = adReq.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new with Java and I'm not sure how to fix this... I get some errors when trying to run your code, the inflater and getActivity() are undefined. Could you please write what exactly should I put in order to compile it without errors.

Comment: Now it compiles without issues, but when I try to run the game it crashes right after starting. :(

Comment: Update your question with the full stacktrace

Comment: adding this -> "yourLayout.addView(adView);"   with fragment, saved my day !! great.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing especially wrong with your layout. Though I would probably change the layout_width for AdView to be:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

But it is not clear what

```
initialize (new RedSquare(), cfg);
```

is doing? I suspect it is altering the layout.