# Ads not showing in my fragment xml in physical device

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I tried hard to view ads but its not working at all.Showing no errors to the codes.

sms.java

```
        adView = new AdView(getActivity());
        adView.setAdUnitId("");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lad);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest= new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

fragment_sms.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.hscresults.sms">
 <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lul"
        android:background="#EF4D26"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#29AB4C"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lad"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                >
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Inside a Viewpager I have added 2 fragments. Android fragments is working all fine but ad is not showing.

Comment: can u upload your logs as well. filter for admob logs

Comment: 07-18 12:20:32.018 29455-29455/com.example.user.hscresults I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
07-18 12:20:32.018 29455-29455/com.example.user.hscresults I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.

Comment: looks like a layout issue - search on stackoverflow with Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. or view solutions given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996175/ad-is-not-visible-not-refreshing-ad

Comment: Thanks bro , It works

Comment: update your question with solution that worked , which will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add onResume and Onpause statement.
Thanks everyone for sorting it out.